# How do I run a page's javascript function?

Tags: pentadactyl

By expecting the html page's code I found that a given link calls `updateAuthors('next')`. Can I call it with [pentadacyl](http://5digits.org/pentadactyl/index)?

There's `execute` and `javascript` (commands?) but inserting the above call after them and hittin return doesn't work.

Comment: Using the `:javascript` command should work if the function is global, however when you click a link there is additional context that is sent to the method that it may be expecting.  Do you see any errors in the messages window when you run `:javascript updateAuthors('next')`?

Comment: @heavyd: I do: `ReferenceError: updateAuthors is not defined`. But calling it in Firebug console works. I just don't want to open firebug. I think it might be possible in pentadactyl.

Comment: Perhaps, try `window.updateAuthors('next')`?  From reading the docs, it sounds like it should work.  Can you access other elements on the page?  `window.location` or `windows.document` fore example?

Comment: @heavyd: it gives `TypeError: window.updateAuthors is not a function`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the trick shown in [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23530203/94928) you should be able to use this command:

```
:open javascript:updateAuthors('next')
```

Answer (score 3):

```
:js content.wrappedJSObject.updateAuthors('next')
```

as described [here](http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.mozilla.firefox.pentadactyl/726).

> The Error Console and Web Console execute code in the page 
>   context. We don't.